# Plotting distplots on one panel for different features with seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe with 12 different features. And I would like to plot histograms for each in one go on a panel 4x3.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [10, 5, -2],
    'b': [2, 3, 1],
    'c': [10, 5, -2],
    'd': [-10, -5, 2],
    'aa': [10, 5, -2],
    'bb': [2, 3, 1],
    'cc': [10, 5, -2],
    'dd': [-10, -5, 2],
    'aaa': [10, 5, -2],
    'bbb': [2, 3, 1],
    'ccc': [10, 5, -2],
    'ddd': [-10, -5, 2]
})
```

I can do it by writing something like the code below:

```
# plot
f, axes = plt.subplots(3, 4, figsize=(20, 10), sharex=True)
sns.distplot( test["a"] , color="skyblue", ax=axes[0, 0])
sns.distplot( test["b"] , color="olive", ax=axes[0, 1])
sns.distplot( test["c"] , color="teal", ax=axes[0, 2])
sns.distplot( test["d"] , color="grey", ax=axes[0, 3])
...
```

[image]

How can I loop and iterate through features in an elegant way instead? I'd like to assign the same four colors for each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can include everything in a for loop:

```
colors =["skyblue", "olive", "teal", "grey"]
f, axes = plt.subplots(3, 4, figsize=(20, 10), sharex=True)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    sns.distplot( test.iloc[:, i] , color=colors[i%4], ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seaborn provides a `FacetGrid` for such purposes.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

test = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [10, 5, -2],
    'b': [2, 3, 1],
    'c': [10, 5, -2],
    'd': [-10, -5, 2],
    'aa': [10, 5, -2],
    'bb': [2, 3, 1],
    'cc': [10, 5, -2],
    'dd': [-10, -5, 2],
    'aaa': [10, 5, -2],
    'bbb': [2, 3, 1],
    'ccc': [10, 5, -2],
    'ddd': [-10, -5, 2]
})
data = pd.melt(test)
data["hue"] = data["variable"].apply(lambda x: x[:1])

g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="variable", col_wrap=4, hue="hue")
g.map(sns.distplot, "value")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely a simpler approach. The OP also needs the same four colors for each row.

Comment: Not sure if that is really needed, but I updated the answer to make the plot colorful, @XiaoyuLu

Comment: It's simpler but I have features of a very different range so the first approach works better for me. Also with 1m rows, it seems like it is quicker too.